# Mean deviation gives better results when deviations are taken from the median, why?

Tags: statistics, means, median

> The mean deviation gives better resuls when deviations are taken from the median instead from the mean, because the sum of the deviations from the median is less than the sum of the deviations from the mean

$$
\operatorname{M.D.}(M)=\frac{\sum|x_i-M|}{N}=\frac{\sum f_i|x_i-M|}{\sum f_i}
$$

This is a widely used statement when defining mean deviation. I understand the proof by which we can say the mean deviation is minimized when deviations are taken from the median. But how come that somehow leads to the statement "mean deviation gives better resuls when deviations are taken from the median instead from mean as the former minimizes the sum of absolute deviations" ?

**Screen shot of sample reference**

Please check [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Zifa38x3YzYC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=mean%20deviation%20gives%20best%20result%20when%20taken%20from%20median%20why%20?&source=bl&ots=6eYLEcxkoc&sig=ACfU3U1Vmfe_SG0MsOTuEE_Y8wU3Rc8iEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqyLDzlbnpAhVNAXIKHerbAbQQ6AEwEXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=mean%20deviation%20gives%20best%20result%20when%20taken%20from%20median%20why%20%3F&f=false) for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Well, "better" is obviously subjective.  People sometimes prefer the median deviation because it is less sensitive to outliers.  But you should clarify what you mean.  Oftentimes people speak of MAD, the [Median Absolute Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation).  That's just the sum of the absolute distances to the median.  That is clearly less sensitive to outliers than the standard deviation, which, after all, squares those extra large distances.  But perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @lulu pls check the link where this statement is added as the 2nd point in the listing of limits of mean deviation : https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Zifa38x3YzYC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=mean+deviation+gives+best+result+when+taken+from+median+why+?&source=bl&ots=6eYLEcxkoc&sig=ACfU3U1Vmfe_SG0MsOTuEE_Y8wU3Rc8iEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqyLDzlbnpAhVNAXIKHerbAbQQ6AEwEXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=mean%20deviation%20gives%20best%20result%20when%20taken%20from%20median%20why%20%3F&f=false

Comment: @lulu my doubt how can we say the mean deviation gives better results when taken from median instead of mean, certainly not about median absolute deviations ?

Comment: I have no idea what "better" is supposed to mean, unless it just means that the sum of the distances is less, which isn't a terribly interesting observation.  Like I say, I frequently use MAD, or other median based results,  when I suspect that my data has bad outliers (but where I don't want to simply strike those from the data set).  Analytically, I prefer to use squared distances as the derivative of the absolute value is problematic at $0$.

Comment: @lulu it says MD from median is better than MD from mean since former is the lowest, doesnt make much sense to me, that is the actual doubt. this statement is found in many books on statistics, which is really confusing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is what you are asking.  As I said, "better" is simply not defined and changes depending on goals and circumstances.  To stress:  these are not $\textit {error}$ estimates, there is no a priori advantage in getting a smaller result.  As I mentioned, if you believe that part of the standard deviation in your data is attributable to unreliable outliers, then this is truly a "better" measure since it cuts down on that effect.  But if you trust your outliers then cutting down their influence is not an obvious plus.

Comment: @lulu: If the aim is to minimise the mean absolute deviation about a point then that point is the (or a) median.  If the aim is to minimise the mean square of the deviation about a point then that point is the mean, if it exists.  In either case, less is seen as better

Comment: @Henry u said "less is seen a better", why is it better, thats the confusing part here ?

Comment: @ss1729  Henry's point, which is perfectly correct as far as it goes, is this:  if you want to summarize the data with a single point AND if you define the accuracy of a point by the sum of the absolute differences, then the median is the right point to use.  That, of course, is precisely what is meant by saying that the sum is minimized by taking the median.  However, why you would use that metric is very subjective,  As I say, there are times when it is a good idea and times when it is a bad idea. Nothing absolute about it.

Comment: @lulu ,Henry okay, can you give me a sample situation where it somehow benefits ?

Comment: I have given you one.  If you want to the most accurate single number to describe the data, where the accuracy is defined by the absolute difference, then use the median.  That really is something.  After all, most people would measure the accuracy of an estimate by taking absolute difference, not squared distance.  Also, as I have said, if you want to estimate the data but you are concerned that the values you have for the outliers are unreliable, use this method instead.

Comment: @lulu so are you saying that if we suspect the outlier data points are possibly unreliable, minimizing the deviations would benefit somehow ? since median minimizes the absolute deviations, choosing it over mean can benfit in that case ?

Comment: No, the outlier benefit is derived by taking absolute differences instead of squares.

Comment: I don't understand what you are after here.  "Better" is subjective, period. The usual thing to do is to take squared distances to the mean.  There are a number of excellent reasons to do that but it is not the only possible measure.  Switching to absolute differences lowers outlier sensitivity (which is either good or bad depending on you attitude towards outliers).  Then, having done that, switching to median improves the quality of the estimator.  Once again, I wouldn't call either of these things "better" but there are times when they might be good properties to have.

Comment: To stress:  if you use squared distances then the mean is the best estimator.  After all, if $f(x)=\sum (x_i-x)^2$ then $f'(x)=-2\sum (x_i-x)$ which is $0$ when $x$ is the mean.  It's only when you switch to absolute differences that the median becomes the better estimator, so any notion of "better", however subjective, has to hinge on using absolute differences.

Comment: @lulu the effect of outlier points get amplified in the process of squaring in the case of standard deviation, $\sigma$. So if we suspect the outlier points are unreliable we can reduce its effect by taking the absolute values instead of squaring, ie. the mean deviation, right ? This is clear i think.

Comment: @lulu last comment you are showing "mean" minimizes "standard deviation". how this fact lead it to be the best estimator in that case ?

Comment: My point was that the mean minimizes the least squared error.  That is to say, the mean is the best estimator if you measure the accuracy of the estimator by least squares, just as the median is the best estimator if you measure the accuracy of the estimator by absolute difference.

Answer (score 1):

Whether item 3 under "merits" is a merit depends on what the purpose is.

Item 3 under "limitations" is nonsense. It does in fact *not* take into account whether an observation is more than the mean or less, at least after the point where the mean is computed, but why would that be a reason to consider anything mathematically incorrect?

Item 2 under "limitations" also depends on what the purpose is.

Item 1 under "limitations" may be subtle.

Now imagine a normally distributed population has standard deviation $\sigma,$ and $\sigma$ is not observable but a finite random sample of $n$ observations is available. The expect value of the mean absolute deviation of the sample is a known scalar multiple of $\sigma.$ Multiplying the mean absolute deviation of the sample by the reciprocal of that known scalar yields an unbiased estimator of of $\sigma.$ Similarly, multiplying the sample standard deviation by another known scalar yields an unbiased estimator of $\sigma.$

**Theorem:** The one based on the standard deviation has a smaller variance than the one based on the mean absolute deviation.

So that's one thing that could be called a demerit of the mean absolute deviation.

However if the population distribution is only slightly different from normal, that is no longer true.

These lists of "merits" and "limitations" look like something written by a person with little understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: You mean M.D$\leq \sigma$ ? "One based on the standard deviation has a smaller variance than the one based on the mean absolute deviation" how can it be a demerit of the M.D ?

Comment: @ss1729 : No, that's not what I meant. When I wrote about a smaller variance, I meant the variance of the sampling distribution of the estimator would be smaller.

Comment: You said "Item 2 under "limitations" also depends on what the purpose is", could you suggest an example where abs deviations taken from median is beneficial ?

Comment: ss1729 : When you're trying to estimate dispersion in a population whose distribution is far from normal, especially if it has heavy tails. For example, with the Cauchy distribution, the sample mean is not at all a good estimator of location, since its distribution is not more concentrated near the center than is the distribution of a single observation; it does not get more reliable as the sample size grows. In that case using the sample median, and the median absolute deviation of observations from the sample median, is immensely better than trying to do anything involving means.